# Declaration/Initialization and memory assignment

Tags: java, memory

**Short:** When is the memory assigned - on declaration or initialization?

**Long:** Will `int x;` take same memory as `int z = 10;`.

Also how will this work for custom Objects that contain more data.
Let's say I have this object:

```
public class Factor
{
    private String name;
    private int value;
    private int time;
    private double x;
    private double y;
    private double z;
    private double h;

    public Factor(String name, int value, int time)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

And then I initialize it with:

```
 Factor f = new Factor("Name", 10, 10);
```

Are *x,y,z,h* (doubles) ever taking memory? ANY?

This might be silly question but simply googling it never gave me answer and I really need this to optimize my multi-constructor object being used in huge array.

Answer (score 1):

> Are x,y,z,h (doubles) ever taking memory? ANY?

**Yes** they do they are initialized with [default value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) which is `0.0d`

however this isn't a key point where you can optimize your memory

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, declaration spells out names and types for variables.

Allocation and initialization occurs when the constructor is called.

Of course doubles take up memory: 8 bytes per double.  It's a 64 bit IEEE floating point number.

It's set to 0.0 f you don't provide an initial value.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Your Factor object is interesting.  Can name be null or blank?  If not, you should guard against setting it to null or blank in the constructor.

Can time be negative?  It's usually a continuous variable in my physics.  What are the units - seconds, fortnights?